# Word matching using external WPF window

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

I have two WPF windows.

1. **MainWindow** which contains a **RichTextBox** called **page1** and a button called **btnFindReplace** which opens up **FindReplace** window.

[page1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoFxW.jpg)

2. **FindReplace** window with two **TextBoxes** and a button called **btnConfirm**.

First TextBox is called "**txtBoxFind**"

[Find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSW3p.png)

Second is called "**txtBoxReplaceWith"**

[Replace & ReplaceWith](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MAGA.png)

/

/

/

**I have a few issues:**

- when btnConfirm Click event is called, the new MainWindow instance opens. How come?
- Regex match is  always false - is it because a new instance opens up and it matches **txtBoxFind.Text** with **no text**, because **page1's text** is **empty** in a new instance? If so, how to fix it? If not, why is always false?

/

/

/

> MainWindow.xaml.cs

**btnFindReplace Click event**

```
    private void FindReplace(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FindReplace findReplaceWindow = new FindReplace();

        findReplaceWindow.Show();
    }
```

> FindReplace.xaml.cs

**btnConfirm Click event**

```
    private void FindOrReplace(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow windowMain = new MainWindow();
        TextRange textRange = new TextRange(windowMain.page1.Document.ContentStart, windowMain.page1.Document.ContentEnd);

        switch (((Button)sender).Content)
        {
            case "Find":
                //Regex.Match(textRange.Text, @"\b" + txtBoxReplaceWith.Text + @"\b");
                
                if (Regex.IsMatch(textRange.Text, @"\b" + txtBoxFind.Text + @"\b"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("found");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("not found");
                }
                break;

            case "Replace":
                //textRange.Text.Replace(txtBoxFind.Text, txtBoxReplace.Text);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Creating a new MainWindow is obviousy wrong. Why are you doing that? You should pass the text from the current MainWindow to the FindReplace window before showing it.

Comment: I'm doing this for the first time. I created a new MainWindow to access "page1" richtextbox. How do I access page1 without creating a new MainWindow?

Comment: As said, by *passing the text from the current MainWindow to the FindReplace window before showing it*, for example as constructor parameter: `new FindReplace(new TextRange(page1.Document.ContentStart, page1.Document.ContentEnd));`

Answer (score 0):

Followed [Clemens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1136211/clemens) advice and passed the page1's text from the current MainWindow to the FindReplace window before actually showing it.

```
    private void FindReplace(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FindReplace findReplaceWindow = new FindReplace(new TextRange(page1.Document.ContentStart, page1.Document.ContentEnd));

        findReplaceWindow.Show();
    }
```

Then made a public TextRange variable and saved **textRange** inside of it.

```
    public TextRange range;

    public FindReplace(TextRange textRange)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        range = textRange;
    }
```

Finally, I re-wrote FindOrReplace event (TO-DO replace function) and everything works
just fine.

```
    private void FindOrReplace(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((Button)sender).Content == "Find")
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(range.Text, @"\b" + txtBoxFind.Text + @"\b"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("found");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("not found");
            }
        }
    }
```